# How to add separator in powershell

Tags: powershell

please tell me, how to add separator in powershell?

I do out command:

```
Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionData.Guest.ToolsStatus -notlike 'toolsOk'} | Select-Object Name, @{N="Tools Status";E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.ToolsStatus}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

and get:

```
Name                          Tools Status
----                          ------------ 

Name1                         toolsOld 
Name2                toolsNotInstalled 
Name3                         toolsOld
```

but me need for format jira:

```
Name                          Tools Status
----                          ------------
|Name1                         |toolsOld|
|Name2                |toolsNotInstalled|
|Name3                         |toolsOld|
```

Can do it with help powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to produce a VERTICAL LINE delimited file, replace `Format-Table` with `Export-Csv` and set the -Delimiter parameter to a VERTICAL LINE.

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property Id,ProcessName | Export-Csv -Path ".\gp.csv" -Delimiter `| -NoTypeInformation
```

If you do not want each field to be quoted, they can be explicitly removed. Note that this removes -all- quotes. If the data contains quotes, a different method must be used.

```
Get-Process |
    Select-Object -Property Id,ProcessName |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter `| -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object {$_.Replace('"','')} |
    Out-File .\gp.csv
```

Alternatively, `Out-GridView` could be used to produce a GUI spreadsheet-like output.

**UPDATE:** for PowerShell 7.0+

`Export-Csv` has a `-UseQuotes` parameter which can be set to `Never`, `Always`, or `AsNeeded`. Use the command `help Export-Csv` for more information.

Comment: complete and useful answer. it worked for me the first solution, export in csv. thanks